# pycrypto works on python2.7 not python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.6, pycrypto

I am using Ubuntu 16 machine. I want to use python 3. I isntalled it. However, I have to use the command `python3` otherwise it runs `python2.7`.

I installed `pycrypto` library using `pip install pycrypto` but when I try to import from `pycrypto` using `python3` I get this error:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

While I do not face the same problem in python 2.7 (the import works fine). What is the problem? how to solve it?

UPDATE:

I tried `pip3` and this is the result:

```
x@x-VirtualBox:~$ sudo -H pip3 install pycrypto
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (2.6.1)
x@x-VirtualBox:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
>>>
```

Comment: `pip3 install pycrypto` ?

Comment: @CristiFati can you check my update please?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have 2 *Python3* instances installed:

1. *Python3.6*:

   - Which is the one you want to use
   - Where *pycrypto* is installed (by *pip3*)
2. *Python3.5.2*:

   - Which is launched by *python3* command

So, you are launching the wrong *Python* interpreter, most likely because *python3* points to */usr/bin/python3* (you can check that by typing `which python3` in your shell), which is *Python3.5.2*, and whose path is in the *${PATH}* env var.

From your *pip* paths, it seems like *Python3.6* is installed under */usr/**local*** (and the executable would be */usr/local/bin/python3*), so you can either:

- Launch the *Python3* executable by its full path (***/usr/local/bin/python3***, as stated above)
- Add */usr/local/bin* to *${PATH}* **before** */usr/bin*, and then simply launch *Python3.6* by typing `python3` in your shell - **but I'd advise against that**
- There are other methods (e.g. creating an *alias*), but I guess you got the idea

***@EDIT0***:

Some more info as requested in comments. This has nothing to do with *Python*, it' all just *Ubtu* stuff:

- To list packages: use *apt* or *dpkg*
- To check *Python2.7* (or any other version): use *which* (as above)
- You don't need to uninstall *Python3.5*. Multiple version can coexist safely
- If you want to make one as default, make an alias (like I did at the end of the example below) and if you want it to be persistent, place it in your *profile* file (e.g. *.profile*, *.bashrc*, *.bash_profile*)

**Examples** (on my *VM*):

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050526408]> apt list python python3
> Listing... Done
> python/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
> python3/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64 [installed]
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050526408]> which python
> /usr/bin/python
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050526408]> ll /usr/bin/python
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 mar 12 16:25 /usr/bin/python -> python2*
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050526408]> dpkg -S /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python2
> python3-minimal: /usr/bin/python3
> python-minimal: /usr/bin/python2
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050526408]> alias python3=/usr/local/bin/python3
> ```

Comment: How can I delete python 3.5.2?

Comment: & also how can I make python3.6.5 the default? and what is the path for python2.7 just in case I needed it?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using python3:

```
pip3 install pycrypto
```